# Passing a C string and using it with a local pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, initialization, variable-assignment

Looking at this code from [The Evils of Arduino Strings](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/evils-arduino-strings)

```
void PrintString(const char *str) {
    const char *p;
    p = str;
    while (*p) {
        Serial.print(*p);
        p++;
    }
}
```

I was looking at reducing/compacting it. Firstly, this seems to be equivalent:

```
void PrintString(const char *str) {
    const char *p;
    p = str;
    while (*p)
        Serial.print(*p++);
}
```

Now, looking at the first two lines, how can I combine the following two lines, is it possible?

```
    const char *p;
    p = str;
```

Can I do this?

```
    const char *p = str;
```

This would seem likely but looks unbalanced, in that there is a lack of an asterisk on the right hand side. I tried it and it seems to work but I was wondering whether it was correct, and worried that I would end up with some *hard-to-track-down* run-time error later on, further down the line.

However, this line below is clearly wrong (as it would change the pointer `p` to point to a location given by the value of the first character of the C string `str`):

```
    const char *p = *str;
```

Comment: How about `for(i=0; str[i] && Serial.print(str[i]); ++i)`?

Comment: `p` and `str` have the same type. Would you have the same doubts if the type were spelled "pointer_to_const_char" instead of "const char *"?

Comment: If you want compact: `while (*str) Serial.print(*str++);`.

Comment: IMO clarity is more important than compactness.

Comment: @molbdnilo - Good point, and I like the compact version. However, I wanted to keep it in a function - oh, I think I see, you mean, do away with `p` entirely, and just use that one line in the function?

Comment: @Rup got your point.
`for(i=0; str[i]; Serial.print(str[i++]));` How about this?

Comment: @Mayur No actually you were right - I thought this was printing string after string, but that would be a ** input. (After all it looks like [Serial.Print](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) can just print a string in one go from the documentation.) This is printing character by character so your initial version is fine.

Comment: `const char *p = str;` ...*looks unbalanced*. You're not after a balanced look but correctness of type. `p` is a `char *`. So is `str`. So it is fine.

Comment: @Greenonline Yes, you don't need a local variable - that could be the entire body. (But I would break it into two lines for readability.)

Comment: @lurker - Excellent, thanks for the conformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> const char *p = str;
> ```
>
> This would seem likely but looks unbalanced, in that there is a lack of an asterisk on the right hand side.

If you separated the elements of the above snippet correctly it would not look "*unbalanced*" at all:

- `const char*` is the type (a pointer to const characters)
- `p` and `str` are the variables, both pointer (to `const char`)

You could write the above using some unconventional layout like this:

```
const char *  /* Note the lack of a semicolon */
p = str;
```

The above code ends up with `p` being defined as a pointer to `char` and carrying the value of `str`.

You get same "result" for the below code

```
const char *p;
p = str;
```

Note that the former is called "initialisation", whereas the latter is called "assignment".

Answer (score 6):

This is obfuscation. The original code is perfectly clear, there is no need to change anything. Your changes make it less readable.

What you *can* do to increase readability slightly, and this is a cosmetic change, is to use a for loop instead:

```
void PrintString (const char *str) 
{
    for(const char* p=str; *p != '\0'; p++)
    {
        Serial.print(*p);
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
void PrintString (const char *str) 
{
    for(size_t i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        Serial.print(str[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @alk The question used an idea which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the use of the p pointer, use directly the str pointer argument, since it is a copy of the pointer to the constant content.

The changes made on str pointer don't affect the pointer used when calling the function, since the pointer is passed by value.

```
void PrintString(const char *str) {
    while (*str) Serial.print(*str++);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing the `while` with `for`. Here's my take:

```
void PrintString(const char *str)
{
    for(const char* p = str; *p; p++)
        Serial.print(*p);
}
```

I think this could work, too:

```
void PrintString(const char *str) {
    for(const char* p = str; *p; Serial.print(*(++p)))
        ;
}
```

As others have pointed out, we can replace `p` with `str`, since `str` is a local copy, just like any other variable passed as function argument.

```
void PrintString(const char* str) {
    for( ; *str; Serial.print(*(++str)))
        ;
}
```